# Nginx server trying to password protect dir gives 403 Forbidden

Tags: nginx, password-protected

I did `sudo htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd user_a` to create my user and pass

Then I added this to my site block location

```
location ^~ /administration {
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}
```

But when I visit url.com/administration and I enter correct username/pass it gives me a **403 Forbidden** page

Comment: What happens if you add a trailing `/` to the URL?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference

Comment: Are the permissions set correctly on `index.html` or `index.htm`?